# Store Image path in MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP file need to save the image in a server and store the image path in a MYSQL database.

My database **imageid** contains table **image_table** as below :

```
create table image_table
(
ID     INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
path   varchar(256),
primary key (ID)
)
```

My PHP Code is as below. Image saving in the server is working fine, but throws few errors storing the image path in DB. 
Error running the below PHP code :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in   C:\xampp\htdocs\appinventor\postfile.php on line 7
```

The PHP Code with above error:

```
   <?PHP
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "basis123";
$database = "imageid"
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";  


@mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

 $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('$_GET['filename']')");
//mysql_query($query);

//File Transfer Logic
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');

if (!(file_put_contents($_GET['filename'],$data) === FALSE)) echo "File xfer completed."; // file    could be empty, though
 else echo "File xfer failed.";

 // $_GET['filename'] has the file name . and C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp is the file path
 echo $_GET['filename']
 //mysql_close();   
 ?>
```

When i remove the database connection and SQLQuery in php code the connection is successful.
Removed lines of code for successful connection and log as "Connected successful"

```
 @mysqli_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

 $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('$_GET['filename']')");
 //mysql_query($query);
```

Where did i go wrong ?Any suggestions ?

Comment: You forgot the semicolon after `$database = "imageid"`

Comment: `@mysqli_select_db` a kitten dies everytime you run this.

Comment: yeah , i m having the issue selecting the db now, how should i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot semicolon after $database = "imageid"

```
$database = "imageid";
```

And you have extraneous parenthesis here:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('$_GET['filename']')");
```

Try this:

```
<?php


    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "basis123";
    $database = "imageid";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";


    mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);

    $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('".$_GET['filename']."')";//also this is unsafe
    //mysql_query($query);

    //File Transfer Logic
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if (!(file_put_contents($_GET['filename'],$data) === FALSE)) echo "File xfer completed."; // file    could be empty, though
    else echo "File xfer failed.";

    // $_GET['filename'] has the file name . and C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp is the file path
    echo $_GET['filename']
    //mysql_close();   
    ?>
```

Comment: here is the echo Connected successfullyUnable to select database

Comment: try using $username = "root";
$password = "root"; to see what happens and doublecheck you database name

Comment: Changing password to root , then error is Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\appinventor\postfile.php on line 9
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Okay, did you try using mysqli_select_db($conn,$database); instead of @mysqli_select_db($database); Put back your old password and try this. I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: DB is now connected , but the path is not stored in db table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68820/discussion-between-user3592479-and-whirlwind).

Answer (score 1):

Main problem:

```
$database = "imageid" 
                     ^----missing ;
$conn = new m
```

PHP strings+arrays 101: You cannot use quoted array keys within a double-quoted string, unless you use the `{}`-extended syntax:

```
$foo = "$arr['key']"; // bad
$foo = "$arr[key]"; // ok
$foo = "{$arr['key']}"; // ok
```

So:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('$_GET['filename']')");
                                                        ^--------^
```

is wrong, as well as being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You seems to be too good , but me being a newbie at php , could nt grab much. Can you please be brief at it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a semi colon after

```
 $database = "imageid"
```

so it should be

```
$database = "imageid";
```

You also don't want to be putting user input directly into your SQL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: adding semicolon at $database = "imageid"; throws error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\appinventor\postfile.php on line 20

Comment: You have another missing semicolon.

 echo $_GET['filename'];

Comment: Also what Marc is saying is also correct. You need to do either $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('{$_GET['filename']}')"); or $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('" . $_GET['filename']  . "')"); BUT DONT DO THAT, see SQL injection docs.

Comment: I m facing error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\appinventor\postfile.php on line 20 using $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('{$_GET['filename']}')"); and Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\appinventor\postfile.php on line 22 using $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('" . $_GET['filename'] . "')");

Comment: Extra parenthesis. $query = "INSERT INTO image_table (path) VALUES('" . $_GET['filename'] . "')";